# docker for windows: RPC from container to outside

Tags: windows, rpc, docker-for-windows

I have a container (NAT network) which runs a service that speaks to other service with RPC (The service inside the container is the client).
When the server is running inside the container's host, the RPC works as expected.

However, When the server is running in other machine inside the domain, the RPC fails, and in the event viewer I can see this:

RpcMgmtInqIfIds
                     Error message description: The RPC server is unavailable.

AND

Error in OpenSCManager
Error message description: The RPC server is unavailable.

Can someone help with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating hosts file inside the container with the server entries, solved the problem.